# Is the FCS field in 802.11 message is mandatory?

Tags: protocols, wifi

[image: From IEEE Std 802.11 - 2012]

**From the 802.11 spec, the FCS field seems be mandatory. But I do see this field is missing in some wifi traffic.**

**What I'm trying to do is decoding the 802.11 messages in my program.**

**If FCS field is optional, how to determine if it's present since the length of FrameBody part may be variable?**

***[Update]***
[image]
The snapshot the parsing result of this capture [mesh.pcap](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=mesh.pcap) from Wireshark SampleCaptures website.

**You can see there is no FCS field in the parsing result.**

Comment: I don't think it's optional. Maybe it is not passed on to you from the underlying layer. How are you parsing the frame? What is its source? Can you post that relevant portion of your code, as well as an input example of a frame that is successfully parsed and of a frame whose parsing fails and the output of your program on processing those frames?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've added an example in the question description. My method is: peek the last 4 bytes of the data, decode it as FCS, then decode the rest data as WiFi MacHeader and WiFi FrameBody.

Comment: By default, some systems strip the `FCS` field from wireless packets. You'll have to see what's going on in your system. The `Radiotap` header includes a bit that specifies whether this field is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, certain firmware strips the FCS while others do not. You would think that the presence of this field would be identified in the MPDU layer where it resides however, it is identified in the radiotap header which means the radiotap parser has to share information with the MPDU parser. To get to it, you have 'unpack' the flags portion of the radiotap and '&' with 0x10